# How can I get a file from the user device if I have the path in C# Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a C# web api project running on Microsoft Azure. I send requests to it via url that then call methods and execute them then return a value back. In one of those methods I pass it the path to a picture (the path to the picture can be from either an Android or an iOS environment). Now I want to get it and manipulate it so I do something like this: 

`Image image = Image.FromFile(pathToFile)`
Unfortunately this does not work since it tries to get the file from the server and not the user's device. How can I get a file from the user device if I have the path in C# web api?

Comment: Instead of sending the path to the file, send the contents of the file.

Comment: There is no way to get a file from a user device through a webbrowser without the users explocit interaction. That would be a *huge* security exploit.

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer, but how can I send a file a URL? I thought about converting ti to bytes and sending it like that but then the URL would be too long, also I dont have a lot of experience with C# web api, I'm sure there is a way, do you happen to know a tutorial of sorts that explains how you can do that?

Comment: this definitely should be a POST request, not a GET through url